Kerrnel Locked Down from EFI secure boot, secure boot disabled in bios
I wanted to ask about something happening on my Debian 12 machine.
When I run journalctl as root I get this message: "Kernel is locked down from EFI Secure Boot; see man kernel_lockdown.7"
I don't have secure boot enabled in bios, is this something else?
I've been concerned about this machine for awhile now.

Is it a recent message, or is it from old journals before you disabled Secure Boot? Have you installed any firmware updates ("BIOS updates") since disabling Secure Boot? Sometimes such an update resets BIOS settings to defaults.

Old journals, sorry and thank you for your help.
